# How can I make a RainDay column from Precipitation values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

```
keytable
Out[66]: 
                        datahora   pp    pres  ...  WeekDay   Power_kW  Power_kW18
Month Day Hour                                 ...                                
1     3   0     2019-01-03 00:00  0.0  1027.6  ...        3  77.303046  117.774419
          1     2019-01-03 01:00  0.0  1027.0  ...        3  72.319602  110.710928
          2     2019-01-03 02:00  0.0  1027.0  ...        3  71.831852  106.067667
          3     2019-01-03 03:00  0.0  1027.0  ...        3  69.555751  106.325955
          4     2019-01-03 04:00  0.0  1027.0  ...        3  69.525780  102.855393
                         ...  ...     ...  ...      ...        ...         ...
12    30  19    2019-12-30 19:00  0.0  1031.5  ...        0  72.590489   89.749535
          20    2019-12-30 20:00  0.0  1032.0  ...        0  71.444516   87.691824
          21    2019-12-30 21:00  0.0  1032.0  ...        0  68.940099   87.242445
          22    2019-12-30 22:00  0.0  1032.0  ...        0  67.244716   83.618018
          23    2019-12-30 23:00  0.0  1032.0  ...        0  68.531573   81.288847

[8637 rows x 12 columns]
```

I have this dataframe and I wish to go through a day's values of 'pp' (precipitation) to see if if it rained in a period of 24, by creating a column called 'rainday' which turns to 1 if a certain threshold of 'pp' is passed during the day. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` with `max` and compare with your threshold:

```
threshold = 1
df["rainday"] = (df.reset_index().groupby(["Month","Day"])["pp"].max()
                   .gt(threshold).astype(int))
print (df)

                        datahora   pp    pres  WeekDay   Power_kW  Power_kW18  rainday
Month Day Hour                                                                        
1     3   0     2019-01-03 00:00  0.0  1027.6        3  77.303046  117.774419        0
          1     2019-01-03 01:00  0.0  1027.0        3  72.319602  110.710928        0
          2     2019-01-03 02:00  0.0  1027.0        3  71.831852  106.067667        0
          3     2019-01-03 03:00  0.0  1027.0        3  69.555751  106.325955        0
          4     2019-01-03 04:00  1.0  1027.0        3  69.525780  102.855393        0
12    30  19    2019-12-30 19:00  0.0  1031.5        0  72.590489   89.749535        1
          20    2019-12-30 20:00  0.0  1032.0        0  71.444516   87.691824        1
          21    2019-12-30 21:00  0.0  1032.0        0  68.940099   87.242445        1
          22    2019-12-30 22:00  1.0  1032.0        0  67.244716   83.618018        1
          23    2019-12-30 23:00  2.0  1032.0        0  68.531573   81.288847        1
```